# Changing the image point resolution for sparsely populated matrix

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, sparse-matrix

I have an image (or matrix) in which the vast majority of the points are equal to NaN and just a few points, which are shown as blue in the example, are known. I want to change resolution, as imresize, of this image (or matrix). But, the problem is that imresize does not work with NaN-filled matrices and if I want to replace the NaN values with some other values, the final interpolation will not be right either. Is there any solution for this? One solution is maybe to use inverse distance with a specific neighborhood and then find the value of new coarse resolution.

[image: Example plot showing sparse points]

Comment: as I said, it changes the accuracy, I am looking for a method to avoid me to do this.

Comment: Yep you're correct, realized it as I posted it

Comment: implement your own simple version that accepts NaN values and resizing should work without touching your precious blues. If you're looking for the same effect as imresize with NaNs in your image, you'll never get those results because NaN has to be dealt with. there is no correct answer with NaNs

Comment: I need a simple method that I use it in matlab, I do not know about that!!

Comment: I think there is a solution! using interpolation methods! But I do not know how

Comment: Well why do you say there is a solution using interpolation methods? Any interpolation you do has math, and NaN's cannot be "mathed" on. I therefore suggested seam carving as a way of removing pixels dynamically without touching your blues if possible. However your image's relative distances will then be changed which you may not want

Comment: I want to change those pixels based on their neighborhood. Imagine that you come close and far from this image, clearly, as you close/open your eye, the resolution will be changed and those points are not exactly the previous ones. In this case, I think I should use an interpolation method.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but any neighborhood algorithm you use will hit NaNs at some point. At which point your math breaks unless you treat the NaNs differently

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple nearest-neighbor:

```
img2 = kron(img, ones(2))  %# for scale factor 2
img2 = kron(img, ones(3))  %# for scale factor 3
...
```

only drawback is you can only have integer-valued scale factors. This makes complete sense, as resizing `NaN` with interpolation is just plain impossible.

As an alternative, you can use

```
img(isnan(img)) = -1;          %# or something else more suited
img2 = imresize(img, 1.2)      %# resize your img normally

img2(img2~=1 | img~=0) = NaN;  %# make everything that's not valid NaN again
```

Comment: tnx for your answer, but as I said, I have some points that are equal to 0 and 1 and I cannot replace the NaN values with a another value, because the results will be changed. Also, the kron dies work for this aim. I think that I should implement an interpolation method that just consider the un-NaN values for interpolation.

Comment: @Sam: Have you actually tried to do this? The values will indeed "change", but you throw those non-0 and non-1 valued pixels away and you are left with a re-sized image containing NaN and 0 and 1, nothing else. You will get some aliasing, but it's the best you can do here. Writing your own interpolations is going to be a mess, and no better than this, I guarantee.

Comment: when I want to try your code, it has an error, the dimension of img2 and img are not equal!

Answer (score 0):

I will only sketch a solution that might work:

1. Make a mask of your matrix where the values are valid
2. Resize that mask
3. Fill the values back in

The first two steps are quite easy:

```
mask      = ~isnan(data);
largeMask = imresize(mask, factor);
largeImage = largeMask;
```

The tricky part is in the last step, which I won't implement, but only show what I'd try to do. I'd order the valid values in the unresized data (`index = find(~isnan(data))`), that way if you can recover that ordering in the larger data, you can just fill them back in. For that recovering, you might want to calculate the `x,y` coordinates of each data point in the small matrix, transform it yourself to the large matrix, find its neighbors and fill in.

*edit:* You might get good results when you resize the mask, resize the data with `NaN` replaced by some value that doesn't distort the values at the points and then re-apply the transformed mask to your image to put the NaNs back in place. Anyhow, this is just a shot in the dark since you don't specify how the data should be interpolated or when you consider the values valid or not.

What I think is a good starting point for some problems is to try to perform the actions manually (or e.g. using GIMP/Photoshop) and then try to implement it in code.

Comment: tnx for your answer, as I found, in your solution these points will not be changed, yes? Because you suggested to just transfer them to the next coarser grid, while they should be changed!

Comment: If you want them to change, you could calculate what they should be when filling back in.

Comment: that is my exact problem that how I should calculate the new values!!

Comment: No need for shouting, but perhaps you might get better answers if you pose your question a bit more clear.